# Why is my programming printing out 1 statement twice and not following execution order?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a bank management program. I ask the user whether they want to login or create an account. If the user enters anything other than 1 (create account) or 2 (login), I want to tell them that they entered something wrong, and then I ask the same question again until they get it right. However, after they enter something wrong, this happens:

1. Program `sleeps` for 3 seconds
2. Error message is printed along with the question for logging in or creating an account
3. The above 2 steps are repeated again except it allows the user to input their option again on the second time

What I want to happen is this (in order):

1. Print error message
2. Print the 3 dots after the error message
3. Ask question again and wait for user input

Here's the **code**:

```
#include "functions.h"

#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J") //function to clear terminal screen

int main(void) {
    clear();
    void (*funcptr)(void);
    int option;
    char *endptr;

    printf("=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================\n\n");
    while(1) {
        printf("Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?\n>>> ");
        option = fgetc(stdin);

        switch (option) {
            case('1'):
                funcptr = create_account;
                break;

            case('2'):
                funcptr = login;
                break;

            default:
                printf("\n\033[0;31m[ERROR] Invalid option. Please enter the number of the option that you want to choose");
                print_dots(3);
                printf("\n\033[0m");
                continue;
            }
        break;
        }
    funcptr();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the **output**:

```
=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================

Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>> 9

[ERROR] Invalid option. Please enter the number of the option that you want to choose...
Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>> 
[ERROR] Invalid option. Please enter the number of the option that you want to choose...
Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>>
```

I've had a similar issue with this before and it was solved with `fflush(stdout)`. The problem is that I don't know where to put this statement, if it is the solution to the problem. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Add a `case('\n'):` to handle the line feed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica wouldn't the `default` label handle that if they leave it blank?

Comment: When you type `X` and return, there are two characters in the input — `'X'` and a newline.  You will get each in turn using `fgetc()`.  Either handle data up to and including a newline (`int c; while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`) or use `scanf()` carefully, or read lines with `fgets()` and parse the input with `sscanf()`, or …

Comment: You are missing the declaration of the `print_dots` function.

Comment: @MatthewSchell: Yes, the `default` label handles newlines, but you are (sensibly) complaining about the way it handles them — by printing the messages a second time.  So you need to handle the newline differently — and `case '\n': break;` is one possible way to do that.

Comment: "wouldn't the default label handle that if they leave it blank?" --> a _new line_ is not a blank.  A _new line_ is the result of the keys your typed.  Post _exactly_ the keys you type. LIke 1, <enter>, 2, <enter>: that is 4 keys.  How do you expect code to handle those 4?

Answer (score 3):

The terminal is in cooked mode (at least that is the Linux term) which allows the user certain amount of command-line editing.  When user is done they press enter ('\n').  What is tripping you up is that the stream (buffer) that `fgetc` reads from contains all the user input including the '\n'.  This means if user inputs "9\n" the first call to `fgetc` will return 9, and the next call will return '\n'.

The suggestion was to add a case for '\n':

```
case '\n':
  continue;
```

This does fix original problem but I am going to `goto next;` instead to avoid the Welcome string being shown twice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define clear() printf("\033[H\033[J") //function to clear terminal screen

void create_account() {
    printf("create account\n");
}

void login() {
    printf("login\n");
}


int main(void) {
    clear();
    void (*funcptr)(void);
    int option;
    char *endptr;

    printf("=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================\n\n");
    while(1) {
        printf("Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?\n>>> ");
next:
        option = fgetc(stdin);

        switch (option) {
            case '\n':
                goto next;
            case('1'):
                funcptr = create_account;
                break;

            case('2'):
                funcptr = login;
                break;

            default:
                printf("\n\033[0;31m[ERROR] Invalid option. Please enter the number of the option that you want to choose");
                printf("...");
                printf("\n\033[0m");
                continue;
        }
        funcptr();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the matching output:

```
=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================

Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>> 1
create account
Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>> 2
login
Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?
>>> ^C
```

Comment: If I did that, the function pointer would be uninitialized. So I went ahead and copied what the default label had into the case you suggested. However, it still didn't work

Comment: "Didn't work" is not useful feedback.  You have a `break;` statement at end of for `while` loop so it only runs once, and then you execute the `funcptr()` once after the loop.  This behavior does not match the output you shared with us.  I  am posting a modified, self-contained program, with the changes to match your output with the invalid option fixed.